# windows 10 How to enable automatic recovery mode without user interaction?

Tags: windows, windows-10, repair, recovery

Sometimes during loading windows 10 I have message that windows is not loaded properly and I have to either to reboot or try advanced setting where I just press Continue and windows 10 loads properly ...

I am wondering if there a way to apply automatic reboot or continue option without user interaction ??

The reason I want it, because I am doing an autonomous system without display and keyboard, and in autonomous mode it is not possible to press or select any such options, and I want that system just continue loading ignore any potential errors or warnings ...

[image: Windows 10 error]

Comment: WinRE always tries to automatically fix an issue when Windows fails to boot twice in a row. IIRC, there's a 30s timeout for the WinRE config menu, so regardless of issue, it should reboot after 30s. What is the _exact_ error message that is being shown, and what is occurring or has changed prior to it being shown?

Comment: Also there may be a reason why this is occurring so you need to consider that and if you need to intervene in these situations.

Comment: I've just added a picture. It is in Ukrainian, it mean Check additional parameters (1 button) and Reboot PC (2 button), error message is: Looks like OS Windows is loaded badly

Comment: I want just ignore this screen and continue loading the Windows 10 without this notification. Something like apply default action

Comment: I have something similar problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb9t5QNflu0